# R: 3D scatterplot with 2 groups not showing up in browser

Tags: r, rgl

Following the tutorial [here](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/3d_scatter_plot.html), I want to create a 3d scatterplot with two colors (blue and orange) representing two different groups. Here is the snippet of my `plot3d` functions, where I am feeding the x y and z values data frame columns of type double:

```
library(rgl)

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot3d( 
  x=population.zero$T, population.zero$M, z=population.zero$L, 
  col = "orange", 
  type = 's', 
  radius = .1,
  xlab="Effective Temperature (K)", ylab=expression("Mass " (M['\u0298'])), zlab=expression("Luminosity " (L['\u0298'])))

plot3d( 
  x=population.one$T, population.one$M, z=population.one$L, 
  col = "blue", 
  type = 's', 
  radius = .1,
  xlab="Effective Temperature (K)", ylab=expression("Mass " (M['\u0298'])), zlab=expression("Luminosity " (L['\u0298'])))

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(rglwidget(), "MLvsT")
```

However, when I view this in the browser, none of the points show up.

[image]

Does anyone know what I am missing here?

(Bonus points: How do I make the figure in the browser appear larger?)

**Edit 1**: Following @G5W's suggestion, I increased the radius to 10. Here are also the data tables for population zero and population 1:

[population 0](https://www.dropbox.com/s/afntlc3q0vcb8gn/test0.dat?dl=0)
[population 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i2e23raletuhyjl/test1.dat?dl=0)

However, I still do not see both populations (only blue, not blue and orange as expected)

[image]

Comment: 1. It would make your question better if you included the library that you are using. Is it `rgl`? Please put the library statement in your code. 2. Since you do not provide your data, I cannot check this suggestion,  but I suspect that your problem is your `radius` parameter or possibly use of spheres. since EffTemp has a range of 800,   radius=0.1 is 1/8000th of the range, too small to plot.  But what radius can you use when the three axes are so different? Try leaving out radius but if that doesn't work, try leaving off `type=s`

Comment: @G5W Please see my edit above. I still cannot plot both populations.

Comment: Your second plot over-writes your first one.  Try just making the orange plot and it should work.   To get both in the same plot,  you must combine the orange and blue data with some indicator of which population each point came from so that you can color the points appropriately. Then just plot once.

Comment: Your link to the tutorial is just a link to the first image.

Comment: @G5W Thank you for your help. This worked. One more thing: Are all the supported types just p' for points, 's' for spheres, 'l' for lines, 'h' for line segments from z = 0, and 'n' for nothing? Are there any more supported types? I am just afraid my spheres may overlap each other, so I am looking for a plus sign or a spiky symbol, for example.

Comment: @G5W, `points` is not relevant:  the OP is using `rgl`, not base graphics.